# Temp Table cannot load content without timing out

Tags: sql

When I am trying to load a page it times out after some time and I have no idea how to edit the query and fix this problem.

The sql is as follows:

```
<createTempTable nml-type="String">
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY
    TABLE temp_tdt
    (subject_id_num bigint) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS not
    logged with replace
</createTempTable>
```

The dataset is not long at all but still this times out.

---

There has never been a problem with having no index in the past, it simply loaded the data no problem, now instead of loading the data it times out the first time and then goes back to loading fast. This SQL is written in websphere in a xlm file. I am looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And I'm pretty sure that `</createTempTable>` is not valid SQL in _any_ DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

We're missing a lot of detail here. But either your temporary table is created for every user (every new connection) or every app restart, plus there is no indexes on this temp table.

Do timeouts occur on the first invocation or after a while? Best change to a proper table with indexed and if you get any timeouts, analyse the queries run against it.